# Laravel : Having lot of problems converting SQL query to query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

i'am having a lot of issue converting this query from MYSQL to laravel query builder... Can somebody help me figure it out ? 
I'am trying to parse all the projects for the actual user (i will replace the 1 value with actual user later), id's are stored on a different base who have id for projets, id for users, and id for companies.

**-- SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM projets, companies, users, userscompaniesprojets 

WHERE 1 = userscompaniesprojets.id_user 

AND companies.id = userscompaniesprojets.id_companies

AND userscompaniesprojets.id_projet = projets.id;
```

**-- Laravel**

```
$companies = DB::table('projets', 'userscompaniesprojets', 'companies')
            ->where('userscompaniesprojets.id_user', '=', '1')
            ->where('companies.id', '=', 'userscompaniesprojets.id_companies')
            ->where('userscompaniesprojets.id_projet', '=', 'projets.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: And what are you getting when you run this query?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output of your query by using the `toSql` method

```
DB::table('projets', 'userscompaniesprojets', 'companies')->
where('userscompaniesprojets.id_user', '=', '1')->
where('companies.id', '=', 'userscompaniesprojets.id_companies')->
where('userscompaniesprojets.id_projet', '=', 'projets.id')->
toSql();
```

you'll see the resulted SQL is

```
select * from "projets" 
where "userscompaniesprojets"."id_user" = ? and 
"companies"."id" = ? and "userscompaniesprojets"."id_projet" = ?
```

this is due to the `table` method only taking a single table see the API [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_table)

You need to make use of joins when constructing this query see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins) once again.

I think something like this will accomplish what you want

```
DB::table('projets')->
join('usercompaniesprojects', 'userscompaniesprojets.id_user', '=', '1')->
join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'userscompaniesprojets.id_companies')->
where('userscompaniesprojets.id_projet', '=', 'projets.id');
```

which results in

```
select * from "projets" 
inner join "usercompaniesprojects" on "userscompaniesprojets"."id_user" = "1" 
inner join "companies" on "companies"."id" = "userscompaniesprojets"."id_companies" 
where "userscompaniesprojets"."id_projet" = ?
```

For more information on Debugging Queries in Laravel check out this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel).